# How to customise chromium keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chromium

Is there any way to customise keyboard shortcuts for current chromium browser?  Because of my Dvorak layout, I often bump ctrl+w when ctrl+v was intended, with disastrous results.

In firefox browser we can do this with the 'keyconfig' add-on, but I prefer to use chromium.

Answer (score 3):

Right now the best keyboard navigation extension for Chromium or Chrome is called [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon), which you can use to easily switch tabs, etc. but also you can fully navigate the web just from the keyboard. The above links to their Chrome store page, which features a nice video demo.