# Disable Google Chrome Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a couple of Web sites that have conflicting keyboard assignments with Google Chrome. For example, there are sites where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on Mac) is a shortcut for Bold or Bullet, but this combination is already used by Chrome to toggle the visibility of the bookmarks toolbar.

The question is simply: how do I disable this and similar shortcuts in Chrome so that the shortcut/function of the web site will work?

There are similar posts, but please note that I want to *disable* a specific set of shortcuts, not *add* new shortcuts! As far as I can see, applications/extensions like keyconfig or Shortcut Manager as described in [customizing chromium keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/q/302822/87274) do not work.

Comment: You are not trying to disable the keyboard shortcuts on the user's side are you?  This is just on your end right?

Comment: I just want to remove the shortcut in my Chrome, so the web sites jI use - e.g. Blogger - works better/properly...

Comment: Would like to know that, too.

Comment: Seems related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162700/how-can-one-disable-shortcuts-of-chrome

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Mac OS X you can alter the keyboard shortcut of any shortcut exposed in the menu bar. You need to take note of the exact name of the menu item you want to change, which in this example is, "Always Show Bookmarks Bar". Then go to the Shortcuts section of the Keyboard preferences in System Preferences. Click App Shortcuts, and add a new Google Chrome specific shortcut that changes the "Always Show Bookmarks Bar" shortcut to something else:

[image: Screenshot of keyboard shortcut preferences]

Return to Chrome and you will see the Always Show Bookmarks Bar shortcut has changed:

[image: Screenshot of altered keyboard shortcut]

Comment: I just have to say this is a life-changing tip! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This allows me to fix one of my greatest frustrations (using Ctrl-D to duplicate a Google Slide adds a bookmark to the slides if the focus is wrong).

Comment: For Windows users, the extension [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-custom-shortc/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) allows you to customize or disable any keyboard and mouse shortcuts in Chrome.

Comment: This helped me stop accidentally switching Chrome tabs when navigating text boxes as I frequently miss-press `option+command+arrow`. I changed it to `control+option+command+arrow` which is a much more deliberate shortcut. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf?hl=en-US) (Shortcut Manager) that may fill your needs.

I did not try it, but it seems to work.

It was mentioned in an [AskUbuntu topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162700/how-can-one-disable-shortcuts-of-chrome)

Comment: Shortcut Manager doesn't appear to work when it comes to replacing builtin shortcuts. I tried adding a shortcut over Ctrl+D then clicking "disable" and "save" -- ctrl+d continued to work.
-
Then I tried enabling the shortcut, and choosing "javascript" and leaving it blank. Ctrl+d continued to work.
-
Ctrl+d also continued to work when I chose javascript, and entered a null javascript expression "()".

In short, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, Cory. It doesn't appear to work in my chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works with MacOS and Windows 7+ and assumes you have an extension installed. If not, go get an extension like [Save to Google Drive.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

1) Type 'chrome:extensions' into your browser's address bar. You will be greeted by Chrome's Extensions menu.

2) Scroll down until you find a link called "Keyboard Shortcuts." Click it.
A window should appear inside Chrome.

3) Pick any extension then click the box alongside it.

4) When the box is active and ready for input, it'll turn a different color and say "Type a shortcut."

5) When you are sure that the box is active, press 'Ctrl+Shift+B', then press
'OK' at the bottom of the window.

What you have just done is override 'CTRL+SHIFT+B' from toggling the Bookmarks bar to doing something non-obtrusive like saving a link to your Google Drive. (I'm assuming you are signed into your Google Account on Chrome.)

Instructions referred to from [here.](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3177326/internet/chrome-ctrl-shift-q.html)